# Error parsing XML: junk after document element, an error in tabhost coding

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to build a tabhost coding and i'm stuck in .xml part.

Here's the following activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Does anyone know the problem in this build?

The message **"Error:(8) Error parsing XML: junk after document element"** appears from the *line 7*.
Hope somebody will know about this problem and could help me, Thank you very much...!!

Comment: Set one Root Layout above Viewpager ,Like Relative or Linear

Comment: You appear to have two root elements here - a `ViewPager` and a `FragmentTabHost`. That's not valid. Did you mean the `FragmentTabHost` element to be *inside* the `ViewPager` element?

Comment: I got it, thanks man. I realized that viewpager root was not included in the end

Answer (score 2):

Problem is multiple root tags.(You can not have two root tags in a single `.xml`)

try this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
      android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: thanks man for the help, it's worked! I have just known that multiple roots